# How can I call member variables of a class within a static method?

Tags: php, class, variables, static-methods

I am using some method to autoload helper files with functions. The only problem I am having now, is how to call the variables in that class.

Because I am not instantiating it as an object, `$this` won't work. But what will?

```
class some_helperclass {

var $some_variable  = '007';

public static function some_func()
    {
    //return 'all ok';
    if (self::some_variable !== FALSE)  
    {
       return  self::ip_adres;
    }
}
```

I can call the function from anywhere now with the help of `spl_autoload_register()`.

```
some_helperclass:: some_func();
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use `self::$some_variable`. Put the $ in there.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

The member variable has to be declared static too.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would have never have thought I needed to include a dollar symbol. PHP is an interesting language at times :/

Answer (score 6):

Declare the variable as static too.

```
private static $some_variable;
```