# How should I share / pass variables across different methods in a PHP Class?

Tags: php, class, function, variables

I am trying to set a value from a method of a class and trying to get it in another method. The example code is as below. I think the below kind of set/get works in a Java class. Googled out but still could not find a relevant solution.

I searched for "how to share data across functions in PHP" and found [How can I call member variables of a class within a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750837/php-call-member-variables-off-a-class-within-static-method), but that did not answer my question.

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    public $cons;

    function showConstant() {
        $this->setConstant(100); /* assign value to variable here */
        $this->showConstantGetter();
    }

    /* setter */
    function setConstant($aCons) {
        $cons  = $aCons;
    }

    /* getter */
    function getConstant() {
        return $cons;
    }


    function showConstantGetter() {
        echo "<br>getting const : ".$this->getConstant(); /* use the variable's value in this method here */
    }

}

$classname = "MyClass";
$class = new MyClass();
$class->showConstant();

?>
```

Answer (score 11):

You must use `$this->cons` instead of `$cons`, that's all.

Comment: +1, sad but true. every time that i go back to code some PHP i forget this... not so intuitive ;)

Comment: Yes, it's very intuitive. That's how objects work. Every language with dynamic object variables requires you to qualify access. Only compiled languages like C++ and Java let you access members without qualifying, but then you might accidentaly "shadow" a member variable. Excplicitly accessing the object is the only way to be unambigous.

Comment: "intuitive" is only a matter of habit. If you programed C++ your whole life and now start using PHP it isn't intuitive obviously.

Comment: Oops sorry, I do not get the values still:

 /* setter */
    function setConstant($aCons) {
  $this->cons  = $aCons;
    }
 
 /* getter */
    function getConstant() {
  $this->cons;
    }

Comment: You forgot the echo in the getConstant

Answer (score 3):

Nearly good but:

```
function setConstant($aCons) {
        $this->cons  = $aCons;
    }

    /* getter */
    function getConstant() {
        return $this->cons;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To access instance variables in PHP, you need to prefix them with `$this->`.

In your example:

```
    function getConstant() {
        return $this->cons;
    }
```

To access a class (or static) variable, you use `self::` instead of `$this->`.

Comment: Class variables are `$this->var;`
Static variables are `self::$var;`

Comment: @Treff "class variable" means "static variable"

Comment: @Artefacto never heard of that terminology solely referring to static class properties. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is this:

```
$this->cons = $aCons;
```

and not this:

```
$this->$cons = $aCons;
```

If you specify `$this->$cons`, PHP will first look at the value in `$cons` and uses that as the name of the instance variable. In your case, there is nothing in `$cons` yet, so it will find a name that is empty, which causes the error message.

This type of indirection is not what you want to do here, so don't put the dollar sign in there twice!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for the answers. That was a very quick resolution. Appreciate it very much. Thanks everyone and all. Here is the complete code which works:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    var $cons;

    function showConstant() {
        $this->setConstant(100); /* assign value to variable here */
        $this->showConstantGetter();
    }

    /* setter */
    function setConstant($aCons) {
        $this->cons  = $aCons;
    }

    /* getter */
    function getConstant() {
        return $this->cons;
    }


    function showConstantGetter() {
        echo "<br>getting const : ".$this->getConstant(); /* use the variable's value in this method here */
    }

}

$classname = "MyClass";
$class = new MyClass();
$class->showConstant();

?>
```